# without L'Hospital: $\lim _{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt[5]{1+3x^4}-\sqrt{1-2x}}{\sqrt[3]{1+x}-\sqrt{1+x}}$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

> $$
> \lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\sqrt[5]{1+3x^4}-\sqrt{1-2x}}{\sqrt[3]{1+x}-\sqrt{1+x}}\right)
> $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\lim _{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt[5]{1+3x^4}-\sqrt{1-2x}}{\sqrt[3]{1+x}-\sqrt{1+x}}=$$

$$=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{\sqrt[5]{1+3x^4}-1}{x}-\frac{\sqrt{1-2x}-1}{x}}{\frac{\sqrt[3]{1+x}-1}{x}-\frac{\sqrt{1+x}-1}{x}}$$

Use the formula/identity $$a^k-b^k=(a-b)(a^{k-1}+a^{k-2}b+\cdots+b^{k-1}).$$

$k\ge 2$, $k\in\mathbb Z$, $a,b\in\mathbb R$.

I'll find one of the limits:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt[5]{1+3x^4}-1}{x}=$$

$$=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(\sqrt[5]{1+3x^4})^5-1^5}{x((\sqrt[5]{1+3x^4})^4+(\sqrt[5]{1+3x^4})^3+\cdots+1)}=$$

$$=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{3x^3}{(\sqrt[5]{1+3x^4})^4+(\sqrt[5]{1+3x^4})^3+\cdots+1}=$$

$$=\frac{3\cdot 0^3}{(\sqrt[5]{1+3\cdot 0^4})^4+(\sqrt[5]{1+3\cdot 0^4})^3+\cdots+1}=0$$

[WolframAlpha says that $-6$ is the answer of your limit.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+%5Cfrac%7B%5Csqrt%5B5%5D%7B1%2B3x%5E4%7D-%5Csqrt%7B1-2x%7D%7D%7B%5Csqrt%5B3%5D%7B1%2Bx%7D-%5Csqrt%7B1%2Bx%7D%7D+as+x-%3E0)

Answer (score 5):

By using a [Taylor series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Definition), one obtains, as $x \to 0$,
$$
\left(1+ax^p\right)^\alpha=1+a\alpha x^p+o(x^p)
$$ giving, as $x \to 0$,
 $$\frac{\sqrt[5]{1+3x^4}-\sqrt{1-2x}}{\sqrt[3]{1+x}-\sqrt{1+x}}= \frac{\left({1-\frac{3}{5}x^4+o(x^4)}\right)-\left({1+\frac{2}{2}x+o(x)}\right)}{{\left({1+\frac{1}{3}x+o(x)}\right)-\left({1+\frac{1}{2}x+o(x)}\right)}}=\frac{x+o(x)}{-\frac16x+o(x)}\to -6.$$

Comment: Using Taylor series is often the most enlightening way to attack these problems, even when L'Hopital is allowed.

Comment: My first choice in this type of problem.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint :**

Rewrite the expression as
$$\frac{\sqrt[5]{1+3x^4}-\sqrt{1-2^{}x}}{\sqrt[3]{1+x}-\sqrt{1+x}}=\frac{\dfrac{\sqrt[5]{1+3x^4}-1}{x}-\dfrac{\sqrt{1-2^{}x}-1}{x}}{\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{1+x}-1}{x}-\dfrac{\sqrt{1+x}-1\strut}{x}}$$
and use the definition of the derivative.

Comment: You beat me! This is how I would have done it. +1

Comment: @ParamanandSingh to upvote an answer to a question that one votes to put on hold looks rather inconsistent to me.

Comment: @miracle173: One needs to judge questions and answers independently based on their quality. I do not downvote mathematically correct answers as a rule even if they are given for poor questions.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I don't think so. This answer prevents that the user improves his question as required by the standards of this sites -> therefore this answer is not useful -> downvote this answer. Just a recommendation, I know thee are different opinions